# Strange algebra question: is this matrix invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, matrix-rank

Let $m>0$ be an integer. Given non-zero real numbers $b_1, \ldots, b_m$, can we always find real numbers $a_{i,j}, i=1,\ldots,m-1$, $j=1,\ldots, m-1$ such that

$$\mathbb \det
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{1,1} & \ldots & a_{1,m}\\
\vdots &  & \vdots \\
a_{m-1,1} & \ldots & a_{m-1,m}\\
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}  a_{i,1} b_i & \ldots & \sum\limits_{i=1}^{m-1}  a_{i,m} b_i\\
\end{pmatrix} \neq 0$$

If so, how can we prove that ? And could we relax the restrictions on $b_i$ (all non-zero) ?

Comment: First of all notice that if all $b_i=0$, then the bottom row is a zero row, which means that the determinant would be zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix will never be invertible as the last row is a linear combination of the others. This also applies to the case $m=1$ in which case we simply have the zero matrix (because the sum is then empty).

And if the matrix is not invertible its determinant will be $0$